# Does there exist a closed set which is an intersection of a collection of infinite open sets?

Tags: analysis

Does there exist a closed set which is an intersection of a collection of infinite open sets?

Comment: Intersect $(-\tfrac{1}{n}, \tfrac{1}{n})$ for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ and consider what set you get

Comment: Oh it will get $\{0\}$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: The question only asks for a "collection of infinite open sets", so just the **singleton** $\{(0,1)\}$ suffices. But Tony, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 8):

$$\mathbb{R}\cap\mathbb{R}\cap\mathbb{R}\cap\cdots$$

Comment: But R is an open set, the intersection is also R so it is still an open set

Comment: And also closed

Comment: While extremely simple, this example has the unfortunate side effect of also being open, which could further confound the OP who seems to be wondering why the intersection of open sets is not open in general (admittedly, the OP is probably also drawing a false dichotomy between open and closed sets, so I suppose this helps with that)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: +1, but I couldn't resist... :-)

Comment: (+1) That's a bad answer from the pedagogical point of view… but it's really funny too!

Answer (score 3):

As other answers and comments point out, this does indeed hold. In fact, *every closed set in $\mathbb R$ is a (countable) intersection of open sets*. This holds in any metric space $(X,d)$. Here is a proof in the general metric case:

Suppose $A\subset X$ is closed. For each $n$, let
$$
U_n :=\bigcup_{a\in A} B(a,1/n).
$$
Note that $U_n$ is open (union of open sets). We claim that
$$
A = \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} U_n.
$$
First note that $A\subset \bigcap U_n$ since $A\subset U_n$ for each $n$ (by construction!). Also, if $x\in\bigcap U_n$, then for each $n$ we have some $a_n$ so that $x\in B(a_n, 1/n)$, i.e. $d(x,a_n) < 1/n$ for each $n$. This implies that $a_n\rightarrow x$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Since $A$ is closed, it follows that $x\in A$. QED.